# QuerySet django returns unnecessary things

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm doing a django app which consists in an e-commerce website.

I have a profile page, and inside I show all articles bought by the connected user. So for that I do a QuerySet:

```
class ProfileView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'eduardoApp/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'order_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id,ordered=True)
```

And in my profile page I do like this:

```
{% for order in order_list %}
<div>
    <p> {{ order.user }}  </p>
    <p> {{ order.articles.all}}  </p>
    <pl> {{ order.ordered }}  </p>
    <p> {{ order.ordered_date }}  </p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The

order.articles.all is returning the following  : `<QuerySet [<OrderArticle: Bottle of Wine>]>`

But my question is : **how do I only display 'Bottle of Wine' ?** Instead of diplaying QuerySet {<....>

Comment: Use another `for` template tag to iterate the `all` queryset and display precisely what you want per item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate through articles

```
   {% for order in order_list %}
    <div>
        <p> {{ order.user }}  </p>
        {% for article in order.articles.all %}
        <p> {{ article.name }}  </p>
        {% endfor %}
        <pl> {{ order.ordered }}  </p>
        <p> {{ order.ordered_date }}  </p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you it's working, just had to change article.name by article !